# UICollectionViewCell not displaying imageView. I added ImageView on top of UICollectionView Using StoryBoard

Tags: uicollectionview, swift2, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am Creating Collectionview Using StoryBoard.I added ImageView on top of UICollectionViewCell. but i can't see any images.

Below is the tutorial link that i am following.
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Swift_iOS_8_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial

Please guide me i am new to ios programming.

Below is my code.

```
//MyCollectionViewCell
```

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

}

class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController
{
    var myArray : NSMutableArray = []

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    myArray = ["a.jpg", "b.jpg"]
}

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let myCell: MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    print(myArray[indexPath.row] as! String) //Prints a.jpg b.jpg
    myCell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: myArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String)
    return myCell
}
```

I already made sure that datasource and delegate are set properly.

Comment: Did you connected imageView outlet?

Comment: Yes I connected imageView outlet.